# Unusual function call in carousel.js source code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I love digging up code in some JS plugins. I lookad at the code of [carousel.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js) and saw the following line of code:

```
this.cycle(true)
```

I don't exactly know what this line of code is doing. Basically I `console.log`ged and found out that the functions inside carousel.js are executed in the following order:

On page load:

```
"inside on" ------------------- [1]
"inside Plugin" --------------- [2]
"inside Carousel" ------------- [3]
"inside pause" ---------------- [4]
"inside cycle" ---------------- [5]
```

Once sliders slide:

```
"inside next" ------------------- [1]
"inside Slide" ------------------ [2]
"inside getItemForDirection" ---- [3]
"inside getItemIndex"  ---------- [4]
"inside pause"  ----------------- [5]
"inside getItemIndex"  ---------- [6]
"inside cycle"  ----------------- [7]
```

That line of code is inside `pause()` , [line 99](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js).

That line of code doesn't seem to be a flag being set or not even a parameter being passed inside `cycle()`, as `cycle` accepts no such parameter. So what exactly is that line of code doing?

Also, without that line of code the carousel works perfectly fine.

Comment: I don't understand why it is so difficult to write word _carousel_ without mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

prototype function has been created in line 55 `Carousel.prototype.cycle = function (e) {` for the respective events.

Comment: but why is `true` being passed as a parameter ??

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening:

Carousel.cycle accepts a single parameter (I don't know why you think it doesn't), and tests if the value of this parameter is truthy. If it is NOT, it sets `this.paused` to false. The confusing thing here is the syntax:

```
 Carousel.prototype.cycle = function (e) {
   e || (this.paused = false)
```

That 2nd line acts as an if statement on the e parameter, implicitly converting it to boolean, and ONLY if it is false, continue processing the second part which sets the `paused` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
Carousel.prototype.cycle = function (e) {
e || (this.paused = false)

this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)

this.options.interval
  && !this.paused
  && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval))

return this
```

The second line is the trick. Generally it triggers `cycle` function without setting `paused` to false